# getRequests() must return an Iterable of arrays

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, parameterized

my code:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)                                                                              
public class FreshResultCompareRunner2 {                                                                   


    //This is called before @BeforeClass !                                                                 
    @Parameterized.Parameters                                                                              
    public static Collection getRequests() throws IOException {                                            
        injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());                                                 
        initStaticFromInjector();                                                                          
        initTestInput();                                                                                   
        return OrganizeTestParameterizedInput();                                                           
    }                                                                                                      


    private static void initTestInput() throws IOException {                                               

    }                                                                                                      

    private static Collection OrganizeTestParameterizedInput() {                                           

        Object[] objectMatrix = new Object[100];                                                
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {                                                         
            objectMatrix[i] = i;                                                                           
        }                                                                                                  
        return Arrays.asList(objectMatrix);                                                                
    }
```

returns the following exception:

`getRequests() must return an Iterable of arrays`

how can i run the parameterized junit with increasing `int` only as input param?

say run the same test for `i=0 ...100` ?

**update**

I have tried

```
//This is called before @BeforeClass !
@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<int[]> getParameters() {
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new MainModule());
    initStaticFromInjector();

    int numOfChunks = 3;//routingResponseShortRepository.getNumOfBaseLineChunks();
    //might be less
    int totalResponses = numOfChunks * globalSettings.requestsChunkSize;

    Collection<int[]> params = new ArrayList<>(totalResponses);
    for(int i = 1; i <= totalResponses; ++i) {
        params.add(new int[] { i });
    }
    return params;
}

//takes the next matrix row from OrganizeTestParameterizedInput()
public FreshResultCompareRunner2(int responseId) {
    this.responseId = responseId;
}
```

and still get an error:

```
java.lang.Exception: com.waze.routing.automation.runners.FreshResultCompareRunner2.getParameters() must return an Iterable of arrays.
    at org.junit.runners.Parameterized.parametersMethodReturnedWrongType(Parameterized.java:343)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For parametrized tests, JUnit passed the test parameters to the constructor of the test class. Because a constructor can take more than one single argument, JUnit expects every parameter set to be an array. The elements of the array must conform to the constructor arguments.

So your configuration method must return an `Iterable` of arrays, e.g. `Collection<Object[]>`. In your case, you just have one single parameter per run, so your array will have a length of 1:

```
@Parameterized.Parameters                                                                              
public static Collection<Object[]> getParameters() {                                            
    Collection<Object[]> params = new ArrayList<>(100);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        params.add(new Object[] { i });
    }
    return params;
}
```

Also note that your configuration method should never do any initialization as your method seems to do! Initialization is solely done in `@Before` or `@BeforeClass`!

Comment: @EladBenda OK, I coded this from memory - possibly the returned collection must be of type `Collection<Object[]>`. I'll check that.

Comment: @EladBenda Fixed the code. Parameter set must be of type `Object[]`.

Answer (score 11):

Junit 4.12+ does not has this restriction anymore. So if you develop your tests with JUnit 4.12+ and then execute those test with 4.11- you will also get this error message.

See [JUnit 4.12 release notes](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.12.md#parameterized-tests) for more details.

Comment: Thanks - this was my point. I replaced junit-4.11.jar by junit-4.12.jar in my groovy -> lib folder, and my parameterized tests worked as expected.

Comment: Great answer. I got this code from a colleague who had it running fine so I was a bit surprised when I got the error

Comment: OMG, I have been going up the wall with this. My POM says Junit 4.11. Fixed now!